# Difference between IOS in-app product tier 1 and tier 1 b?

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase

When i am trying to create in-app products it shows prices like tier1 as well tier1b, what is the difference between that?

Comment: okey. Thank you. So if i define my in-app price 1.99$ and if someone frome india try to buy then the price automatically converts to 60 INR?

Comment: Yes, that happens for all price tiers. The 1b price tier is for newsstands apps only

Comment: I have one more doubt. Is it possible to create in-app product for custom price. ie prices like 10.56$ or 256.33$

Comment: No, you have to pick one of the prices from the list

Comment: okey. Thanks for the help